# Set newlength relative to another

Tags: lengths

I would like to define a new length, and set its value equal to a given fraction of an existing length, e.g.

```
\newlength\halftext
\setlength{\halftext}{0.5\textwidth}
```

However, the second argument of \setlength only accepts numerical values in given units, e.g.

```
\setlength{\halftext}{10truecm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.! Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document, which demonstrate your problem.  If I put your definition in standard article document work fine. What is actually your problem?

Comment: The standard `\setlength{\mylen]{0.5\textwidth}` sets `\mylen` to half the `\textwidth`. If it doesn't work for you then you need to show us what you have done (from `\documentclass{... ` to `\end{document}`)

Comment: both forms you use are valid, although latex doesn't really support `true` units much.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Both expressions work fine indeed, if isolated in a simple document. I'm now realizing that the weird outcome I'm presently experiencing comes from using such dimensions as width of pictures embedded in boxes (`\savebox`), which are then used within a `minipage`: I suspect that a nested use of `\textwidth` is to be avoided ...

Comment: @PeterWilson I was struggling why \setlength{\mylen]{0.5\textwidth} works and e.g. \setlength{\mylen}{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep} wasn't. Turns out, you need 
\usepackage{calc}. I think they need to include it in standard MikTeX/Overleaf distribution.